# From PostgreSQL to SAS

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas, pgadmin

I have a 40MM lines table in PostgreSQL (that I've imported from 50 smaller CSV files) and queries take too long. I'd like to send it to SAS.
I'm not a programmer. How do I do it?

PS: Is there a new file created of 38MM lines that is physically on my computer ? I guess I don't get how the DB works.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions I'm pretty sure your query could be improved (40 million rows is really not _that_ big)

Comment: If you don't have SAS/ACCESS to ODBC or Postgresql then you can always read in the CSV files into SAS fairly painlessly.

Comment: Hi Reese,I tried but 1) my EFI tool doesn't work (dont know why. I have SAS 9.3 and Windows7 Pro x64). 2) For some files, the format and informats go really bad and I dont know how I fix it into the ProcImport... That why I pass through DBMS... thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

SAS has the ability to connect to an external relational database, then use the contents of that database as if they were a SAS data set. So, you could pull the data down using a SAS `data` step or using `proc sql` and then analyze it on your machine. To do this you'll either need SAS Access to Postgres, or you'll need SAS Access to ODBC and the Postgres ODBC driver installed on your machine, with the database set up as a data source under Administrative Tools in the Control Panel. This article should point you in the right direction: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/66787/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0nc2tikruabp6n1008nkdf0buee.htm

More importantly, though, I might try submitting your SQL code for review. If you're only hitting 40 million records, the query really shouldn't take all that long unless you're doing something really complex.